# How to disable or hide one field when another text field has any text and re-enable that field if the other text box is cleared

Tags: java, hide, disable

I need to disable or hide a series of text fields if the first field has any entered text. Then, if the first field is cleared of text, I need the other fields to become visible (fillable) again. I'm using Acrobat XI.

The code below works, but not well. When the text in field Global N/A is deleted, the other 14 fields stay hidden. If I repeatedly enter and delete text from Global N/A, the fields will eventually become visible (fillable) again. I do not want a checkbox and need this to work seemlessly. Please note, I'm new to Java so I'll need very specific steps. Thank you!

```
function updateFormField()
{
   var v = this.getField("Global N/A").value;

   if (v == "")
   {
      this.getField("Hull1").display = 

display.hidden;
      this.getField("Hull2").display = 

display.hidden;
    this.getField("Hull3").display = display.hidden;
    this.getField("Hull4").display = display.hidden;
    this.getField("Hull5").display = display.hidden;
    this.getField("Hull6").display = display.hidden;
    this.getField("Hull7").display = display.hidden;
    this.getField("Hull8").display = display.hidden;
    this.getField("Hull9").display = display.hidden;
    this.getField("Hull10").display = display.hidden;
    this.getField("Hull11").display = display.hidden;
    this.getField("Hull12").display = display.hidden;
    this.getField("Hull13").display = display.hidden;
    this.getField("Hull14").display = display.hidden;
       }
   else 
{
      this.getField("Hull1").display = display.visible;
      this.getField("Hull2").display = display.visible;
      this.getField("Hull3").display = display.visible;
      this.getField("Hull4").display = display.visible;
      this.getField("Hull5").display = display.visible;
      this.getField("Hull6").display = display.visible;
      this.getField("Hull7").display = display.visible;
      this.getField("Hull8").display = display.visible;
      this.getField("Hull9").display = display.visible;
      this.getField("Hull10").display = display.visible;
      this.getField("Hull11").display = display.visible;
      this.getField("Hull12").display = display.visible;
      this.getField("Hull13").display = display.visible;
      this.getField("Hull14").display = display.visible;

   }
}

updateFormField();
```

Comment: This is not java, is it?

Comment: Hmm. I thought so? I snagged this from somewhere and thought it was java. I'm happy for any code that will do the job that I can enter into Acrobat XI.

Comment: @ Red Hunt:  <br/>I also tried this code:<br/>`code`     if(event.value == "") { // equals nothing
    this.getField("Hull1").display = display.visible;
    }     else     {
    this.getField("Hull1").display = display.hidden;
    }